# Can Angular forms be configured to fire validation on button click (form submit)?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Out of the box Angular template driven forms seem to validate input on each keyup.  I know you can use Observables with reactive forms to modify when validation fires, but I am looking for a faster way without observables to have the Angular form validation fire on submission, like many user experiences require and expect.

Comment: Why without Observables? The validation is being run every time an input changes. You can subscribe to any form control, array or group to see its validation status at any time

Comment: Thinking through some examples for an intro to Angular presentation and wanted to walk through the most basic form examples.  Don't want to scare away people with heavy Rxjs usage.  But upon some more thought, it does seem like Observables are intrinsic to the way Angular forms work.

Comment: Just have a function that checks for validity on click of relevant fields looks to be the way

Comment: It does indeed!

Comment: Actually, you don't even need observable. You have `FormControl.valid: boolean` that you can use when you click the button. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valid